# How to make the GLSurfaceView transparent

Tags: android, opengl-es, background, transparent

I am drawing the object on GLSurfaceView using opengles. But GLSurfaceView is not the transparent. Instead of transparent its completely black in background.

Please help me how to make the GLSurfaceView transparent.

I used this code

```
setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What i do to get around this is I have regular view such as LinearLayouts within the xml and i call 
linearLayout.addView(glSurface); 
linearLayout2.addView(glSurface2);

After that i call them by the order i would like:
linearLayout2.bringToFront();
linearLayout.bringToFront();

Let me know if you would like me to post code.